# Does inode number determine what files were created earlier than others?

Tags: ext4, inode

In an `ext4` filesystem, suppose that `file1` has inode number `1`, and that `file2` has inode number `2`. Now, regardless of any `crtime` timestamp that might be available, is it wrong to assume that `file1` was created earlier than `file2` only because inode `1` is less than inode `2`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Lower inode number doesn't prove older.

A simple case that would change that sequence is deleting a file which would free the inode.  That inode therefore becomes available for future use.